# Eclipse Luna Loses Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: eclipse, keyboard, shortcut, eclipse-luna

After Eclipse Luna is running for a certain amount of time, it loses keyboard shortcuts and I can't use some single keys like <kbd>delete</kbd> anymore. Any ideas why this is happening?